# Determining if VBA If Then Statement is necessary to code and how to fix Compile Error

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to set a Range ("headers") that is from a cell containing "Period" to cell containing "Agent Split". At the end of the code I select all of these ranges to make sure it's working properly.

I had tweaked the following code that contained a For loop

```
Sub Rangeheaders_test()

 Dim r As Long
 Dim endRow As Long
 Dim endCell As Range
 Dim headers As Range

  With ActiveSheet

    endRow = 500
 For r = 1 To endRow

    If .Cells(r, "A").Value = "Period" Then
       Set endCell = .Rows(r).Find(What:="Agent Split", LookIn:=xlValues,_
    LookAt:=xlPart, After:=.Cells(r, "A"))

       Set headers = .Range(.Cells(r, "A"), endCell)
    End If
  Next r
   End With

    headers.Select

End Sub
```

However this code ran through the ranges and only selected the last when I wish to select them ALL in order to test it. So I deleted the loop which left me with the following

```
  With ActiveSheet
   endRow = 500

  r = 1 To endRow

    If .Cells(r, "A").Value = "Period" Then
       Set endCell = .Rows(r).Find(What:="Agent Split", LookIn:=xlValues,_
    LookAt:=xlPart, After:=.Cells(r, "A"))

       Set headers = .Range(.Cells(r, "A"), endCell)
    End If
  End With

    headers.Select
```

But now I'm either getting a Syntax Error or Compile error for Unexpected With or If close and I'm stuck. Do I need to define the Then condition? Is the If Then statement even necessary? Is there another way i can set the conditions?

Comment: `r = 1 To endRow` is not a valid line, `For r = 1 To endRow` is

Comment: @Chronocidal should the line be Set r = 1 To endRow

Comment: No, because [1 is not an Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement).  `To` is only used in Arrays and Loops

Comment: Your first code is only saving the last set of range because you overwrite the previous value every time it finds "Period". You are storing the range in the variable called "headers" which only takes one value at a time. You need to store the ranges in a "list". I recommend creating a string value with each range separated by a comma. That way you can convert it to a list by using the split method later on. Ex. RngList = "A1:A5, A7:A8, A10:A11". Looping - RngList = RngList + "," + "Your new range value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized from @Jun 's insightful comment that i was trying to store multiple ranges in *one* variable and that's where i was going wrong.

After some research i found the Union method where I'm able to combine my ranges after i specify them -- which i did using the `.Findnext` method

```
Sub findheader()

Dim startcell As Range
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A500")
    Set startcell = rng.Find(what:="Period", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Dim header1, header2, header3 As Range
    Set header1 = Range(startcell, startcell.End(xlToRight))

        Set startcell = rng.FindNext(startcell)
        Set header2 = Range(startcell, startcell.End(xlToRight))

             Set startcell = rng.FindNext(startcell)
             Set header3 = Range(startcell, startcell.End(xlToRight))

Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Union(header1, header2, header3)

headers.Select


End Sub
```